# Free memory works well on GCC build but not on MSVC

Tags: c++, gcc, memory, visual-c++, free

I'm recently trying to migrate my C++ application from Mac (gcc) to Windows (MSVC2010). But two lines in my code is causing crashes:

```
if (block != NULL)
    free(block);
```

These two lines work perfectly fine under gcc on Mac OS, but crash on Windows. If I commented them in Visual Studio it will lead to memory leak. "block" is alloc-ed as:

```
uchar* block = (uchar*)malloc(_bytes_per_pixel * _width * _height);
memset(block, 0xff, _bytes_per_pixel * _width * _height);
```

and it's later passed to an API function from another library populating its value.

I wonder what may cause free() to crash, and why it only crashes under MSVC(Windows) but not gcc(Mac OS). I'm new to c++ and stackoverflow so I would highly appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: How `block` is allocated? Or are you using `block` after these 2 lines?

Comment: Is there any instance where you would have already freed `block`? IE, a double free?

Comment: Are you sure that `block` points to an address that was allocated rather than garbage?  The test is unnecessary; `free()` ignores an attempt to `free()` the null pointer.

Comment: Thanks Flávio. I'm not using "block" afterwards. I also added some info in the question.

Comment: Thanks GraphicsMuncher. I don't think there's any double free, but i'll double check. If it somehow is actually a double free, would gcc(Mac) ignore double free but MSVC won't? is that possible?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I think "block" is at least pointing to something because if I don't free it there will be memory leak (on Mac), and if I free it everything is fine (also on Mac).

Comment: What is the reason it crashes? Run it via debugger and tell us the exception you get. Breakpoint at every place where use see a free(block) and check whether more than one free is triggered. It's a good practice to set the pointer to zero after freeing, so you can easily spot if it's invalid. free() itself is *not setting it* to zero. You have to do it manually (if you want).

Comment: Another possibility is that the code that uses the allocated block is writing out of bounds and messing up the control block used by `malloc/free`